# Dock icons settings lost after reboot

Tags: dock

I have installed 12.04 on my desktop machine, everything works fine except for a few annoyances.

All modifications I do to my dock (I add/remove icons) are lost upon reboot/logout.

If it helps, I've done a clean system install but I have been keeping my home folder. My previous system was 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Unity.
For that, launch the terminal and run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, upon logging in and out, my dock settings are back to default.